# Ошибка ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS на BitrixVM 5.55

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, битрикс, centos

## Существует проблема с редиректом в BitrixVM v.5.55.2

Есть VPS, на нём несколько доменов. На одном домене установлен Интернет-магазин Битрикс. Далее был создан второй домен через меню BitrixVM, на который был перенесен старый сайт на WordPress. *Всё было нормально, до момента установки SSL сертификата.*

Сейчас наблюдается на сайте с Wordpress постоянный редирект 301, а точнее **зацикленный редирект**.
Я грешу на nginx, логи ничего внятного по крайней мере для меня не дают.
Самое интересное, что в саму админку Wordpress удалось зайти и внутри не возникает проблем.

## Окружение:

- CentOS 6.8
- ISPmanager Lite 5.55.2
- BitrixVM 5.1.8
- 1CBitrix интернет-магазин на одном домене
- WordPress на другом домене, с которым и возникли проблемы конфигурации

***В каталоге ниже есть файлы:***

**/etc/nginx/bx/site_avaliable**

- bx_ext_lokalsite.ru.conf
- bx_ext_ssl_lokalsite.ru.conf

## Содержимое bx_ext_lokalsite.ru.conf

```
# Ansible managed: 
/etc/ansible/roles/web/templates/nginx/http_newsite_template.conf.j2 
modified on 2016-06-23 13:19:43 by root on mywebsite.ru
# Additional website http
    server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name lokalsite.ru www.lokalsite.ru;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/lokalsite_access.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/lokalsite_error.log warn;
#charset utf-8;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_faorwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host:80;
    set $proxyserver  "http://127.0.0.1:8887";
    set $imcontenttype  "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set $docroot        "/home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru";
    index index.php;
    root "/home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru";
#Redirect to ssl if need
    if (-f /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/.htsecure) { rewrite ^(.*)$ 
    https://$host$1 permanent; }
#Include parameters common to all websites
    include bx/conf/bitrix.conf;
#Include munin and nagios web
    include bx/server_monitor.conf;
}
```

## Содержимое bx_ext_ssl_lokalsite.ru.conf

```
    #Ansible managed: 
        /etc/ansible/roles/web/templates/nginx/https_newsite_template.conf.j2 
        modified on 2016-06-23 13:19:43 by root on mywebsite.ru
    #Additional website http
        server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name lokalsite.ru www.lokalsite.ru;
    #enable SSL connection
        include bx/conf/lokalsite.ru_ssl.conf;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/lokalsite_access.log main;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/lokalsite_error.log warn;
    #charset utf-8;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host:443;
        proxy_set_header  HTTPS YES;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        set $proxyserver  "http://127.0.0.1:8887";
        set $imcontenttype  "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        set $docroot        "/home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru";
        index index.php;
        root "/home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru";
    #Include parameters common to all websites
        include bx/conf/bitrix.conf;
    #Include munin and nagios web
        include bx/server_monitor.conf;
}
```

## Вот такой ответ получаем 10 раз на сайте https://bertal.ru/

```
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Server: nginx/1.8.1
    Date: Sat, 31 Mar 2018 00:12:47 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Connection: keep-alive
    Vary: HTTPS
    Location: https://lokalsite.ru/
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

## Вот так выглядит конфигурационный файл апача bx_ext_lokalsite.ru.conf

```
#Ansible managed: 
    /etc/ansible/roles/web/templates/httpd/bx_apache_site.conf.j2 modified on 
    2016-06-23 13:19:43 by root on kalif24.ru
#site: lokalsite.ru<pre>
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8887>
        ServerName  lokalsite.ru
        ServerAlias www.lokalsite.ru    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot  /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru
        ErrorLog logs/lokalsite_error_log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog logs/lokalsite_access_log combined
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Nginx should have "proxy_set_header HTTPS YES;" in location
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} =YES
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTPS:on,L]
    </IfModule>
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <DirectoryMatch .*\.svn/.*>
        Deny From All
    </DirectoryMatch>
    <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
        Deny From All
    </DirectoryMatch>
    <DirectoryMatch .*\.hg/.*>
        Deny From All
    </DirectoryMatch>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        php_admin_value session.save_path /tmp/php_sessions/ext_www/lokalsite.ru
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir    /tmp/php_upload/ext_www/lokalsite.ru
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/bitrix/cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/bitrix/managed_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/bitrix/local_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/bitrix/stack_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/upload>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/upload/support/not_image>
        AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/bitrix/images>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/lokalsite.ru/bitrix/tmp>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

День убил на поиск ошибки, не знаю где она.
В конфигурационных файлах Линукса я слаб.
Может быть кто-то знает где может быть собака зарыта?

Comment: При переключении WordPress на https,  с ним надо произвести определённые действия: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Answer (score 0):

Помог мне решить данную проблему один разработчик фрилансер. Всё оказалось очень просто.

Проблема закралась в файле bx_ext_ssl_lokalsite.ru.conf, а точнее в порте 443 в строке

```
proxy_set_header    Host $host:443;
```

привел строку в вид

```
proxy_set_header    Host $host;
```

и всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Также такое может произойти из-за htaccess, если сервер на apache. Попробуйте открыть файл в `.htaccess` в корне сайта, и удалить строки

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Эти правила говорят что если запрос прилетел не на порт 443 то сделать редирект на https версию сайта. На некоторых серверах, например на локальных https версия может слушать и не 443 порт, поэтому удаление решит проблему, при желании можно не удалять, а изменить и вместо 443 записать порт на котором работает ваша версия сайта на https